# Among his greatest hits (were?/was?) the anthem. Which verb is correct?

Tags: verbs, grammatical-number

I read [this article](https://www.voanews.com/a/4221563.html) and found a sentence that says:

> Among his greatest hits **were** the anthem "Bring Him Back Home," demanding Nelson Mandela's freedom from jail.

Could you explain why the sentence used 'were' as the verb? I think the subject and the object are inverted in this sentence. Therefore, it can say that

The anthem "Bring Him Back Home," demanding Nelson Mandela's freedom from jail **was** among his greatest hits.

So the subject is the anthem "Bring him back home" and I thought its verb should be 'was' because the anthem is in the singular.

I would appreciate a little bit of help.

Comment: You have correctly identified a grammatical error.

Comment: Agreed.  If you just see "hits were" or "hits was" you (or your computer grammar checker) may mistakenly  choose "were" to agree in number with "hits".

Comment: I've seen a computer grammar checker object to the correct "was" in a similar situation and recommend changing it to "were". (But this happened some years ago; maybe computer grammar has improved since then.)

Comment: It's a simple case of space editing. The original must have referred to two or even three but due to space constraints, the rest were later dropped leaving just one and the *were* stayed, overlooked by the subs. Take it easy, folks.

Answer (score 1):

It is an error. The correct form of that clause would be

> "Among his greatest hits **was** the anthem "Bring Him Back Home"

As you said, a singular verb (*was*) should be used to match the grammatical number of the singular noun "anthem".